# Traveling across the United Kingdom by car

Tags: planning, sightseeing, uk, itineraries

Me and my friends had an idea of going to the UK by car and travel across the country to see as much as possible. I would like ask if someone can share his opinion of where to go and where to don't go. We are all 20 years old students interested in "beauties" (history, nature etc.) of country and also interested in having fun in good clubs :) .

We will go from the Slovakia and the "journey" should be no longer than 2 weeks. It can contain anything except Northern Ireland (I have nothing against Ireland, I am sure Northern Ireland is as beautiful as rest of the UK, but that would take a lot of time to go there by ship etc.)

If someone could give me list of what to not miss in the UK, I'd be grateful! I don't need hotels etc., just the best places to visit! :)

If there is a similar question to this one then I'm sorry, couldn't find it.

**EDIT:**

We are interested only in Wales, Scotland and England. We don't have to visit London, we've been there already once. We don't want to visit every museum in every town. Just the most known, main, places, or maybe it doesn't have to be a most known. I just want to know, like, what would you visit if you go on a road trip across the Great Britain. I know there are infinitely many places to visit. We want to spend only at most 1 day in every town (I know it is not enough for big towns..). All of us like history and beautiful scenery. We don't want to go hiking, play golf (:D) or do sports.. We just want, when we come back, to tell everybody that the Great Britain is such a beautiful country:)

Comment: I think this is a bit broad for the stackexchange format. Maybe if you define a region in the UK this question can be answered.

Comment: Yea I know, but didn't want to create more questions. We'd like to travel across whole country, not just one region.

Comment: @DávidKaya You still better ask per region and what you are interested in. You could stay only in London for 2 weeks. If people don't know if you like hiking, museums or touring golf courses, it will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit this question and add more details.

Comment: I would make a question specifically on how to get to the UK. There are different option (Calais-Dover, Zeebrugge-Ediburgh, HoekvanHolland - Harwich, Amsterdam Newcastle, etc). Entering the country already decided quite a lot on what is possible in 2 weeks

Comment: As the question is now, it is to broad to answer, hence the close-vote

Comment: @Andra What is the difference between making questions for every region and making one questions with all regions.. Someone with knowledge about the Great Britain should be able to give an opinion about what is worth visiting. I don't want to know where to turn left on road... I want to know what are the most interesting places according to someone who knows about GB more then me. And I will decide how to get to GB after deciding where I want to go...

Comment: @DávidKaya As per the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) and well established practices across many if not all StackExchange sites *give an opinion* is considered non-constructive for the simple reason that opinions vary.

Comment: @DávidKaya I come from the UK, but I think there are other countries in Europe which are far more beautiful, both architecturally & in landscape. I think you shouldnt try to drive the length of the UK in 1 visit - only choose a couple of areas by that I mean counties. Once you have decided on that, then ask the question.

Comment: This page answers your question: http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/United_kingdom

Comment: However this questions gets modified to a smaller area, I fear it stays 'too broad' or 'unsuitable' for this site, due to its nature. Better to leave this as it is, you got one answer that will suit you, it is unlikely you get better or even good other ones. (Look at other Q&A sites or just search with the basic Q, as a lot of information is already online.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So much to see...

Obviously this is very very very subjective and there is too much too see - so here are a few inspirations from my wife and my experiences. Your tastes may vary.

2 of us "did" England, Scotland, Wales, Eire and a splash or Northern Ireland in 2 weeks. Run the whole time. See much. Collapse exhausted when you get home.

FWIW our look-around philosophy is like yours and less like some respondents'. Given 2 weeks in a large area we would rather run like mad and see a little of as much as possible, rather than have  an in depth look at some small part. We would love to see more detail everywhere, but you can see so much in one day in an area if you are prepared to push yourselves to the limit. This is not everyone's idea of how to holiday !!! :-).

Get a National Trust pass. Expensive - and worth every GBP of it.  Cost based on duration. Buy shortest snd sell/give to friends. Then have free entry to so so so much. Castles, gardens, more. Not everything alas.

If want [beautiful/amazing/weird/impressive/utterly different - see Portmerion](http://www.portmeirion-village.com/).   Utterly fake and artificial - but also marvellously mystical and 'romantic'. 
A longish haul to the coast but things to see along the way and utterly astounding. The ITV program "The Prisoner" filmed here. All my life I'd longed to see it, never expecting to. I was so pleased to be able to do so. Alas, a vast number of other people want to do so too. That's life. Avoid weekends I guess. Great. DO NOT get caught by the tide - dangerous bore. It's mainly "The Prisoner" fans who do that.
Photos composite below is from above site:

[image]

[Portmeirion - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmeirion)

[Portmeirion images and links - worth a look](https://www.google.com/search?q=portmeirion&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=E4FdUfDNKOeoiAf49oCgDQ&ved=0CGAQsAQ&biw=1745&bih=982)

---

If you like technology at all, even just driving past [Jodrell Bank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodrell_bank)  will excite you. Talker to far flung Space Craft, searcher for aliens, listener to stars. Very impressive.

[image]

There are two working boat lifts in the UK - taking barages / canal boats and flinging them (not overly fast) skywards or down.

One is a wheel - [The Falkirk Wheel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkirk_Wheel)
Ginormous. Amazing.
Wikipedia image:

[And the Anderton Boat Lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderton_Boat_Lift) old and restored and marvellous in quite different ways.

[image]

Also : http://canalrivertrust.org.uk/Anderton-boat-lift

Oxford is worth a quick peek.
All the colleges - often open to public view.
 All closed the day we passed through :-( - except one.
Which was the one I most wanted to see ! :-) - Magdalene - C S Lewis, Old building, history, impressiveness, choir stalls carved to exquisite perfection, more.

See a few Cathedrals.
Plenty in Europe but the British ones are also good.

Super special for us - may or may not be for you:
Coventry Cathedral !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
The symbol to the Bristish people in WW2 of stubborn and resolute resistance.
 The bombed shell defiant against the foe.
 So, after the war, did they rebuild it, did they raze  it ?
 Yes and no. Inspired. The outer wall of the old rebuilt somewhat, clkear open space in middle. Plaques. Performances, ... , 
And next door joined at the hip the new "modern" Coventry Cathedral.
Ground glass angels like you've never seen before, or since.
 The then largest tapestry in the world (French made) at the front.
 little alcoves and chapels and nooks. A feeling of real understanding of the message of Christ. Of Peace & love & reconciliation and servanthood and ... .
If that is not you it may not be you. For me it was stunning.
 And, of course, the church is twinned with a sister church in a German city.
 Lest we forget !
All images below from Wikipedia.
Walk where Churchill walked 70 years ago.
See, almost, what Churchill saw, plus, now, so much more.

[image]

You can fly into eg Dublin with minimal loss of time. Rough and ready and cheap sometimes Ryan air will have you there in under an hour as I recall and off the plane so fast you'll wonder what happened. We stayed in a hostel on Batchelors Walk about 30 seconds from the very centre of Dublin. Marvellous. A few days in Eire allows you to see much.

If you want to see a **real** castle then Raglan Castle in Wales is superb. The last to hold out in the Roundheads/Cavaliers war. 14 foot thick stone walls in places (really). Much remains. Moat amazing. Separate keep accessible from main castle with its own moat.

If you want to  see a picture book / calendar / chocolate box castle (**you do**!) see Bodiam Castle, somewhat south of London. If you see a castle on a chocolate box there is a good chance this is it. It looks right, feels right, set in a pretty mote/lake, across water approach pathy, turrets , walls, all the right stuff.
 Its "real" and it also "fake". Its a real castle BUT it was buolt as much for show as for defence. Walls are far thinner than Raglan. 30 bedroorms -  a 30 room party house. Guests from all over, entertaining, social status etc. STILL worth seeing. Very very pretty. Nice feel. Good photos.
[**Many Bodiam Castle images here** - DO look](https://www.google.com/search?q=bodiam+castle&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=5wNeUajZAeWoiAex_YGYBw&sqi=2&ved=0CE4QsAQ&biw=1745&bih=982)

Just a few views:

[image]

If you spent your youth reading Wordsworth and longing to see Tintern Abbey you can - at last. But they shut it after hours.But just the drive down the Wye valley, thickly thatched cottages, little pubs, utter English country beauty is magical.

Images below from [this wikipedia images search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bodiam+castle&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=5wNeUajZAeWoiAex_YGYBw&sqi=2&ved=0CE4QsAQ&biw=1745&bih=982#hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=wye+valley&oq=wye+valley&gs_l=img.3..0l10.449487.451434.0.451770.10.8.0.2.2.2.344.1353.3j1j3j1.8.0...0.0...1c.1.8.img.JNNEAJmXuik&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.aGc&fp=c09e82951f04447a&biw=1745&bih=982)

[image]

Comment: Just a small point of order The Prisoner was not a BBC television program it was made for the ITV network the BBCs competition at the time.

Comment: @Sarriesfan - thanks - altered. If that's the only point worth changing I must have done OK as an antipodean. Amazing how few upvotes such an answer gets. Not done for the votes, fortunately.

Comment: You did not get upvotes because the question and this answer do not suit the site. It is a good answer as it is for an other site. Stack Exchange is a facts sites and opinion based answers, and questions asking for those, are not welcome. Both Q and A would do well on a site where opinions are welcome.

Comment: @Russel I think you meant 'Roundheads/Cavaliers' - Crusaders were something else entirely!

Comment: @peterG Thanks. Yes. Altered. Brain fade. It took 5 years for anyone to comment on that :-).